# Rollup is making a large bundle size almmost 4 times greater than webpack for Reactjs app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webpack, rollupjs

I am learning the Rollup and make the configuration file as the below, it was making the bundle of 404kb just for the hello world app, on the other side if i bundle the app with webpack the size was around 120kb.

```
export default {                        
    input: "src/index.js",                        
    output: {                         
         file: "dist/bundle.js",                         
         format: "umd",                         
        sourcemap: true,
    },                        
    plugins: [ 
        resolve({                          
            extensions: [                           
                ".js",                            
                ".jsx"                          
            ]                         
        }),                         
        babel({
            exclude: './node_modules/**'
        }),                        
        commonjs(),    
        uglify()                    
    ],                       
}
```

I am running the bundle with rollup -c command

can anybody help me withh what i am missing in the configutation

Comment: did you ever find out what's causing this? My Rollup bundle is 2x the size of the same project using Webpack